# Escape all metacharacters in Python

Tags: python, regex, metacharacters

I need to search for patterns which may have many metacharacters. Currently I use a long regex.

```
prodObjMatcher=re.compile(r"""^(?P<nodeName>[\w\/\:\[\]\<\>\@\$]+)""", re.S|re.M|re.I|re.X)
```

(my actual pattern is very long so I just pasted some relevant portion on which I need help)

This is especially painful when I need to write combinations of such patterns in a single re compilation.

Is there a pythonic way for shortening the pattern length?

Comment: Why use `.*?` at the end if it matches an empty string? Also, you do not have to *ever* escape any chars in the character class except for shorthand classes, `^`, `-`, `]`, and ``\``. There are ways to keep even those (except for ``\``) unescaped in the character class.

Comment: In addition to the comments, this smells like a job for `xml` **parsing** (node name???).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ***my actual pattern is very long so I just pasted some relevant portion on which I need help***.Would be great to get an answer to what was asked. I am not yet an expert on regex in python, so generally escape meta characters. Probably will learn over time on which to escape and which not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look, your pattern can be reduced to

```
r"""^(?P<nodeName>[]\w/:[<>@$]+).*?"""
```

Note that you do not have to ever escape any non-word character in the character classes, except for shorthand classes, `^`, `-`, `]`, and `\`. There are ways to keep even those (except for `\`) unescaped in the character class:

- `]` at the start of the character class
- `-` at the start/end of the character class
- `^` - should only be escaped if you place it at the start of the character class as a literal symbol.

Outside a character class, you must escape `\`, `[`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `$`, `^`, `*`, `?`, `.`.

Note that `/` is not a special regex metacharacter in Python regex patterns, and does not have to be escaped.

Use raw string literals when defining your regex patterns to avoid issues (like confusing word boundary `r'\b'` and a backspace `'\b'`).